# Proper Constructors to Run all Methods in Java

Tags: java, class, object, methods, constructor

I have this class and need to know which constructor is needed to create an object that may immediately use all its methods without error

```
public class Robot {
    private boolean fuelEmpty = true;
    private int roboID;
    private String greeting;
    private String securityProtocol;

//insert robot constructor here

public void destroyAllHumans(){
    while (fuelEmpty == false) {
        //robot begins to destroy all humans
    }
}
public int getRoboID(){
    return roboID;
}
public void greet(){
    System.out.println(greeting);
}
public void setSecurityProtocol(String proto){
    securityProtocol = proto;
}
}
```

For example should look like this:

```
public Robot(int id, String greet) {
    roboID = id;
    greeting = greet;
}
```

or this:

```
public Robot(int id, String greet) {
    roboID = id;
    greeting = greet;
    fuelEmpty = false;
}
```

or:

```
public Robot(boolean full, int id, String greet, String proto) {
    roboID = id;
    greeting = greet;
    fuelEmpty = full;
    securityProtocol = proto;
}
```

Which of these (or something else different) is needed so that all the other methods can run without an error?

Comment: offtopic: you should do ***while (!fuelEmpty ) {*** instead

Comment: As the `destroyAllHumans` method has undefined body, it is hard to tell which class members are needed. What is a `securityProtocol ` for?

Answer (score 1):

You can overload the constructor as much as you need, the important thing is
the object gets properly instantiated after you create a new one...

a way can be:

```
public Robot() {
    this(false, 0, "", "");
}

public Robot(int id) {
    this(false, id, "", "");
}

public Robot(boolean fuelEmpty, int roboID, String greeting, String securityProtocol) {
    this.fuelEmpty = fuelEmpty;
    this.roboID = roboID;
    this.greeting = greeting;
    this.securityProtocol = securityProtocol;
}
```

so look how all other constructors will at the end call internally the

```
public Robot(boolean fuelEmpty, int roboID, String greeting, String securityProtocol)
```

that will give you the waranty that no matter which constructor is invoked, the Robot is fully created and can invoke all those methods without crashing

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you prefer to call `this(false, 0, "", "");` in the no arguments constructor instead of `this(0)`? To clarify: there is nothing wrong with it, I would have used the "shorter" constructor, so I'm just curious about why you chose the other one :) Is there any "standard" behind the choice or is it just your preference?

Comment: nope... am just elaborating the multiple options that OP has

Answer (score 1):

The solution works like this:

- you look at each of your methods
- you check which *fields* each method is using
- you check more closely, if the method breaks when that field has its *default* value (like `null` for Objects, or `false` for booleans)

When you do that for all methods, you get a list of those fields that you **need** to initialize somehow. Then you could go forward and define a corresponding constructor.

But of course, that is the **wrong** approach.

The *real* answer goes like this: you don't put fields into a class because you *can*. You add them because they are required so that this class can implement the requirements (responsibilities) that you want it to implement. Meaning: you focus on the methods that your class should provide. Then you clarify which fields you need in order to implement these methods.

In other words: you have exactly those fields in your class that your class needs. If you have fields in there that go unused - then you get rid of them.